# How to make a prediction with Random Forest in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I have got the following model

```
modelo_rf13 <- randomForest(df_depurado13$CuT_Calc ~ df_depurado13$XRF_Geomet)
```

My dataset is as following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnnuE.png)

As you see, it has 4 columns: HOLEID, Litologia, Cut_Calc and XRF_Geomet

Now, I want to make a prediction for the following values of XRF_Geomet

```
c(0.25750, 0.25290, 0.31710, 0.34140, 0.34220, 0.37080, 0.38540)
```

The problem is that I get this error. If you could help me to solve it, I would really appreciate it.

```
Error in yhat[keep] <- ans$ypred : 
  NAs no son permitidos en asignaciones subscritas
Además: Warning message:
'newdata' had 7 rows but variables found have 57 rows
```

Comment: Don't use `df_depurado13$` in your formula. That locks your parameter to that data.frame and doesn't allow you to predict. Use `randomForest(CuT_Calc ~ XRF_Geomet, data=df_depurado13)`